# Turn off volume control and mute button in HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-video

We have some videos playing great in our HTML mobile app. However, our videos don't have sound, just subtitles, so we need to remove the volume slider and mute button but keep the timer bar.

Can this be done or toggled with HTML or CSS? Or is some javascript required to do this?

At the moment the setting within our html tag is just: *controls="controls"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super easy:

Your html should be something like:

```
<video id="Video1">
  <source src="..." type="video/mp4">
  <source src="..." type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Add then a customized button to play the video:

```
<button id="play" onclick="vidplay()">&gt;</button>
```

Finally a progress bar:

```
<progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

Then in javascript add a button to play

```
var video = document.getElementById("Video1");

function vidplay() {

       var button = document.getElementById("play");
       if (video.paused) {
          video.play();
          button.textContent = "||";
       } else {
          video.pause();
          button.textContent = ">";
       }
    }
```

And a listener to update the progress bar:

```
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgressBar, false);


function updateProgressBar() { 
var progressBar = document.getElementById('progressbar'); 
var percentage = Math.floor((100 / mediaPlayer.duration) * mediaPlayer.currentTime);
 progressBar.value = percentage; progressBar.innerHTML = percentage + '% played'; 
}
```

So basically **remove** the "standard controls" and create your own ones.

If you wanted to achieve more complicated results, I would recommend you another option. This could be using a more configurable setting such as [video.js](http://videojs.com/).

Comment: I still need to keep the timer bar ideally

Comment: The user will probably want to scrub the video using the progress bar as well, perhaps a input/range control is better (or catch click events on the progress bar).

Comment: Of course is possible to be done, yet that has cost in maintainability. I think it would be a rather good choice to adopt a tool such as popcornjs or video.js to do so.

Answer (score 18):

This has worked:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
display:none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the controls attribute from the video element completely.

Try Here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_controls. Remove the "controls" attribute and the bar will disappear.

Comment: I still need to keep the timer bar ideally

Comment: Have you tried these references? 1.http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos                                                    2.http://www.creativebloq.com/html5/build-custom-html5-video-player-9134473                                                 3.http://www.inwebson.com/html5/custom-html5-video-controls-with-jquery/